# If BeanFactory holds bean definitions, which class holds actual bean instances?

Tags: java, spring

It's stated in [BeanFactory's doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html), that it

> is implemented by objects that hold a number of **bean definitions**

If BeanFactory, or ApplicationContext (that is also a BeanFactory) hold bean definition, what class is responsible of holding actual beans?

It's said also that BeanFactory is

> The root interface for accessing a Spring bean container

What class is this container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't really matter as it's an implementation detail, unless you intend to work with the internal classes. But for example singleton beans are by default contained in a map in [DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.3.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java) etc.

The container isn't a single class, it refers to spring as a whole.